# Log4j2 on EJB module with glassfish java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, log4j2, glassfish-4

I have a EJB Module using Netbeans and glassfish 4, and log4j2.
I have a Singleton Session Bean with an schedule.
This is my class:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@Singleton
public class MyClass {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
@EJB
private MyFacadeLocal myFacade;

public MyClass() {
}

@Schedule(hour = "11", minute = "15", dayOfWeek = "Fri")
private void doSomthing() {
    logger.info("Hello");
}
}
```

I need to implement log but I'm having this problem when deploying:

```
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB MyClass: [java:global/MyProject-ejb/MyClass, java:global/MyProject-ejb/MyClass!com.mydomain.schedule.MyClass]
SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory.<init>(SLF4JLoggerContextFactory.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:85)
at com.mydomain.schedule.MyClass.<clinit>(MyClass.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.instantiateOptionalEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(BaseContainer.java:3807)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.initializeHome(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:222)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.SingletonContainerFactory.createContainer(SingletonContainerFactory.java:72)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 70 more
```

Glassfish logging works only with older log4j on this scenario?
How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace it looks like you have the log4j-to-slf4j-[version].jar in the classpath. This is the Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter jar that allows applications coded to the Log4j 2 API to be routed to SLF4J. Probably not what you want. (If this ***is*** what you want then you also need the SLF4J jars on the classpath.)

The log4j2 download archive contains many jars, but you only need the LOG4J-API-2.0 and the LOG4J-CORE-2.0 jars.

Comment: I only have this dependencies for log4j-api and log4j-core: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

Comment: I forgot something... the operating system is ubuntu 64 bits, and runs with oracle jdk. I have no idea how to fix it. :( thanks

Comment: Solved adding this files "log4j-api-2.0-beta7.jar" log4j-core-2.0-beta7.jar to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/ext. There is a way to do just with maven dependencies, Tag scope?

Comment: Charles, I still think you have the log4j-to-slf4j jar in your classpath. That is the only thing that would explain the stack trace above. I'm not sure why your solution solves the problem. It forces the core and api jars to be at the beginning of the classpath, so perhaps core is now found first and the log4j-to-slf4j classes are never loaded. It should be possible to just use maven dependencies... Your pom snippet looks fine, as far as I can see... Could it be caused by something else in your pom?

Comment: My pom is very simple, org.apache.logging.log4j, junit, org.glassfish.main.extras, javax. Thanks for your time. I accept this solution.